# How to Move or Copy Folders using directory Wildcards within Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to set up a batch file that will copy files from a preset directory, several layers down, organized into a folder in the current directory using batch files.

The file structure looks something like this,

> > AAA
> >     --0001
> >     ----textures
> >     ------file1.tga
> >     ------file2.tga
> >     ------file3.tga
> >     --0002
> >     ----materials ...
> >     --0003
> >     ----textures ...
> >     --0004
> >     ----scripts ... etc
> >     --0005 ...
> >     --0006 ...
> >     BBB
> >     --0001 ... etc
> >     ---textures ... etc
> >     CCC ...
> >     DDD ... etc

I want to move each textures, materials, models (etc.) folders into a single folder beneath the parent item (eg. AAA) so that the folder structure then looks like this, with all sub-files in tact,

> > AAA
> >     --textures
> >     --materials
> >     --models
> >     --scripts

I've been trying to use a code similar to this, with no success as of yet,

> > for /d %%a in ('dir /b .\AAA*\textures') do copy "%%a" ".\AAA"

Whereas the wildcard would go between 'AAA' and 'textures' folders. The same would apply for every other 2nd-generation sub-folder.

I just tried another version of the command which moved the files, but not the folder. I'm launching the batch file from within the "AAA" folder.

> > for /d %%a in (0001) do copy "%%a" "."

I think the issue is not knowing how to properly input directory wildcards into the "for" command, which could be a very simple fix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated beyond measure.

Comment: I suggest you replace `copy` by `robocopy`which has lots more features: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx which is available since Win 7

Comment: So it was `robocopy` that moved the folders, and not `copy`. Though I'm inclined to ask about `/f "tokens=*"` - what does that do?

Comment: Nevermind. Just researched it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in a `.bat` file, and run it inside your AAA directory

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b') do robocopy %%a . /s /move
```

- `for /f "tokens=*"` means that all the returned values by `'dir /b'` will be processed
- `dir \b` will list the directory in bare format
- `robocopy` is the main command, that will do the copy job.
- source `%%a` is the variable containing the iterated subfolder name {`0001\textures`, `0002\materials`, ...}
- destination `.` means copy to the working directory, which is AAA in our case
- option `/s` to search subdirectories
- option `/move` to move instead of copy

Comment: That was BEAUTIFUL! That did exactly what I needed it to do. (Though I don't understand how.) What would I need to do in order to run it one level up? (Outside my AAA folder?)

Comment: Also, appending `/move` instead of `/mov` handles much of my cleanup for me.